# Verification of assumptions in TBATS model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, diagnostic, tbats

I have a question about using BATS/TBATS models implemented in the *forecast* package for R. In [De Liv­era, Hyndman & Snyder (2011)](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/) the models are used without any following analysis. Is it OK to use these models this way? Shouldn't there be at least verification that the residuals are a Gaussian white noise, which is an assumption for BATS/TBATS models? 
Many thanks